# 401 Unauthorized Response for Angular

Tags: angular, authentication, spring-security, authorization, http-status-code-401

I am trying to make a login page to my website with using Spring Security and Angular. Even if authorization works on Postman, it doesnt work on Angular.

Here my SecurityConfiguration class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors();
        http.csrf().disable().
                authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**","/login","/faqbio/auth").
                fullyAuthenticated().and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

When i pass username and password using Basic Auth on Postman, it works as you can see:

[image]

Here my auth service on Angular:

```
  auth(request : UserRequest): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(request.username + ':' + request.password) });
    return this.http.post<any>("http://localhost:8085/faqbio/auth",{headers});
  }
```

I tried to pass username and password as hardcoded but it didnt work.

Here my network tab:
[image]

Can you help me to fix this issue? Thank you.

Comment: I suspect you have a CORS error as well..

Comment: Also, check in your browser console devtools, on the network tab, your request contains your Authorization header.

Comment: @MikeOne I had getting CORS error until i add @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200") annotation to controller. Now error status is 401 at the console network tab.

Comment: @RicardoMachado i inspected header there but couldnt find the username and password values.

Comment: Becayse if you read the angular api, first parameter is the url, the second parameter is the body and the third is options. So you are passing the headers in the body parameter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the issue with replacing PostMapping to GetMapping.